# Как в браузерной версии Telegram имитировать клик по кнопке отправки сообщения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telegram

Как в браузерной версии Telegram имитировать клик по кнопке отправки сообщения?

Comment: `document.querySelector("ссылка на кнопку").click()`, но если обработчик проверяет событие на `event.isTrusted === true`, то ничего не выйдет.

Comment: @MishaSaidov в том то и дело что проверка есть, какая я понять не могу. Такое не работает, через тригер тоже не вызывается.

Comment: "`isTrusted` - свойство объекта `Event`, принимающее значение `true`, если событие было инициировано действиями пользователя, и `false`, если событие было создано или изменено скриптом". Также существует проверка, находится ли мышь над кнопкой или нет. Если такие проверки есть, то не стоит даже пытаться (+ весь код у них обфусцирован). Если это возможно, в вашем случае, попробуйте копнуть в сторону API.

Comment: @MishaSaidov Api не вариант, так как надо в бот канал чужой отвечать, а токена соответственно нет, думал может как-то через браузерную версию можно будет что-то да сделать :/